# Laravel Mailgun tracking emails

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun, laravel-8

I'm trying to track emails sent via laravel mailgun driver. I want to be able to view the emails in the 'analytics' page of app.mailgun.com.

I am able to send emails using Postman with the following headers: `o:tag o:tracking o:tracking-clicks o:tracking-opens` and these seem to work fine. I can see these in the 'analytics' page. I have also successfully set up web hooks so I can track individual events for each email.

According to the documentation if I am sending via SMTP I need to send these tags:  `X-Mailgun-Track: yes, X-Mailgun-Track-Opens = yes`. I have set these using the following code in the build method of my mailable class:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
   $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
       'X-Mailgun-Track', 'yes'
   );

   $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
      'X-Mailgun-Track-Opens', 'yes'
   );
});
```

I can see these headers are added when I open the email in a text editor. The email does not show up in the mailgun 'analytics' page.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you've confirmed the headers are added, then this stops being a programming question and starts being a product support question.

Comment: i think the working header is `X-Mailgun-Tag`

Comment: @ZeroOne thank you very much! This is what I was missing.